# Angular 2 - setting default value in dropdown when default is hard coded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor, angular2-ngmodel

I have the following dropdown.  I want to set All Patients as the default value.

```
    <select [(ngModel)]="searchModel.careprovider">
      <option [value]="0">All Pateints</option>
      <option *ngFor="let user of practiceUsers" [value]="user._id.$oid">
        {{user.dn}}
      </option>
    </select>
```

My model is declared this way:

```
searchModel: any = { location: null, practice: null, name: '', careProvider: 0 };
```

I set the practiceUsers this way:

```
  this._practice.getUsers(this.searchModel.practice).subscribe(result => {
    this.practiceUsers = result;
    this.searchModel.careProvider = 0;
  });
```

No matter how I change it I always just get a blank option as the default.  I've tried adding an object to the `this.practiceUsers` array after it is loaded, then setting the model value.  I've tried setting the model value with and without quotes to see if a number or string made a difference.  Everything I try still results in the default being the blank option.

In Angular 1 I would have used `ng-options`, but that is no longer available for Angular 2, and every example I find shows to use the `ngFor` for dropdowns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object attributes are case sensitive, in your object, attribute is called `careProvider`, but in your template, you are using `searchModel.careprovider` with lowercase `p`. I think you also have to use `NgValue` directive instead of `value` because you  are using `NgModel` directive. So, this should work: it is not working

```
<select [(ngModel)]="searchModel.careProvider">
  <option [ngValue]="0">All Pateints</option>
  <option *ngFor="let user of practiceUsers" [ngValue]="user._id.$oid">
    {{user.dn}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Isn't that always the case?  You scour the code only to find it's a simple type causing all the problems.

Comment: @Jhorra I totally feel you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [selected] attribute. I solved similar problem this way:

```
<select>
   <option *ngFor="let option of options" value="{{option.id}}" [selected]="option === selectedOption">
      {{option.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

I hope this helps a little

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" id="policeid_country_id" name="policeid_country_id" formControlName="policeid_country_id">
    <option [ngValue]="null">Select</option>
    <option [ngValue]="country.id" *ngFor="let country of countries">{{country.country}}</option>
</select>
```